# How to use data stored in cache with SWR hooks, and how to make SWR fetch only one time

Tags: reactjs, swr

I have a component that fetch data on mount thanks to a useEffect hooks. I'd like it to not refetch data on mount, and instead use the 'cached' data provided by useSwr hooks when i re-navigate to this component. Im not sure how to do this. What i have read is that you can call swr like this :

```
const { data } = useSwr('same route as previous one')
```

and it 'll gives you the data stored in cache by the previous swr call.

```
const CategoryList = ({setLoading}) => {

    const [category, setCategory] = useState('');
    const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false);
    const [parameters, setParameters] = useState({});
    const company_id = localStorage.getItem('company_id')

    const session = new SessionService();
    const { dataFromFetch, error } = useSWR([mounted ? `${session.domain}/company/${company_id}/category-stats` : null, parameters ], url =>
      session.fetch(url, {
          method: 'GET',
      })
      , {
          onSuccess: (dataFromFetch) => {
            setCategory(dataFromFetch)
            setLoading(false)
            setMounted(false)
          },
          onError: (err, key, config) => {
            console.log("error", err)
          }
      }
  )

  useEffect(() => {
    setMounted(true)
    setLoading(true)
  }, [])

    return (
        <div className={classes.CategoryList}>
            <h5>Parc de véhicules</h5>
            <div className={classes.CategoriesCards}>
            {category.data? category.data.map((element, index) => {
                return <CategoryItem
                            category={element.data.name}
                            carNumber={element.stats.nb_vehicles}
                            locating={element.stats.nb_booked}
                            available={element.stats.nb_available}
                            blocked={element.stats.nb_unavailable}
                            percentage={(element.stats.nb_booked / element.stats.nb_vehicles * 100).toFixed(2)}
                            key={index}
                        />
            }): null}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default CategoryList;
```

Plus, in an other hand, i'd like my SWR hooks not to consistently try to refetch data like it is dooing actually. What i tried is passing options after my fetcher function, like it is stipulate in this post [SWR options explanation](https://github.com/vercel/swr/issues/450). Actually my component is trying to refetch data every 5-10seconds, though unsuccesfully thanks to my 'mounted' condition which result in a 'null' route ( which is the recommended way to do it according to the documentation ). It still sends a request with response 404, which i'd like to avoid.

```
const [parameters, setParameters] = useState({
      revalidateOnFocus: false,
      revalidateOnMount:false,
      revalidateOnReconnect: false,
      refreshWhenOffline: false,
      refreshWhenHidden: false,
      refreshInterval: 0
    });
    const company_id = localStorage.getItem('company_id')

    const session = new SessionService();
    const { dataFromFetch, error } = useSWR([mounted ? `${session.domain}/company/${company_id}/category-stats` : null, parameters ], url =>
      session.fetch(url, {
          method: 'GET',
      })
      , {
          onSuccess: (dataFromFetch) => {
            setCategory(dataFromFetch)
            setLoading(false)
            setMounted(false)
          },
          onError: (err, key, config) => {
            console.log("error", err)
          }
      }
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

According to SWR's documentation, the hook's API is

`const { data, error, isValidating, mutate } = useSWR(key, fetcher, options)`

In your code, you're passing the options as part of an array in the first argument, when it should be the third.

A minor refactor shows how it can be fixed:

```
const parameters = {
  revalidateOnFocus: false,
  revalidateOnMount: false,
  revalidateOnReconnect: false,
  refreshWhenOffline: false,
  refreshWhenHidden: false,
  refreshInterval: 0,
};

const company_id = localStorage.getItem( "company_id" );

const session = new SessionService();

const fetcher = (url) =>
  session.fetch(url, {
    method: "GET",
  });

const key = mounted
  ? `${session.domain}/company/${company_id}/category-stats`
  : null;

const { data, error } = useSWR(key, fetcher, parameters );
```

You've also over-complicated your code quite a bit - there's no need for `onSuccess` or `onError` handlers - you can simply use the returned values `data` and `error` instead.

Also, no need to save the fetched data to state by using `setCategory`. Just read directly from `data`. That's the benefit of of SWR  It will auto-magically trigger re-renders when data is fetched.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Though, if i decided to use a hook on success to store data again, it's because "data" is always empty outside onSuccess, i dont know why. I can't "read" data, it's always undefined... Any explanation?

Comment: `data` certainly should include the fetched data. It's difficult me for to diagnose because I can't use your fetcher or endpoint. A couple of suggestions:

a) try removing `revalidateOnMount: true` and see if that's preventing the fetch.
b) is `error` returning anything?
c) i don't know how the variable `mounted` is set - is that preventing the fetch?
d) does your fetcher function return a promise that resolves the data? Try debugging the fetcher in isolation.